# Making GPS module work

Tags: gps, arduino, xbee

We have trouble figuring out how to connect the GPS to the satelite. We are using the TinyGPS library at the moment. The Arduino is sending signals, but isn't receiving any response from the satelite itself. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Using:

Arduino Uno
XBee pro shield
XBee GPS Bee

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(1, 0);

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. ");    Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude  Longitude  Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt      Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum");
  Serial.println("          (deg)     (deg)      Age                      Age  (m)    ---          from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail");
  Serial.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

  ss.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
  print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 11, 6);
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  print_date(gps);
  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " :       TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (unsigned   long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
  print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
  print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  Serial.println();

  smartdelay(1000);
}

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
  Serial.print(' ');
  }
      smartdelay(0);
    }

static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
   Serial.print(sz);
  smartdelay(0);
}

 static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  unsigned long age;
  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
    Serial.print("********** ******** ");
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d ",
        month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
      smartdelay(0);
     }

static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
      smartdelay(0);
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain of the `SoftwareSerial` pins (`/* ...pins 4(rx) and 3(tx) */` vs. `ss(1, 0)`)? Also, can you be sure that you receive good NMEA sentences within your 1000ms window?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that GPS module connected to D0 (TX wire) and (D1 RX wire).
2. Check GPS module default settings for serial. Probably you should try `ss.begin(4800);`or other default connection speed.
3. Ensure that smartdelay code is executing at least once(put debug string there). Probably you've got unhandled exception in loop() function which prevents from read any data from GPS module.